# How to allow Sagemaker studio to access data stored in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm trying to read data that is stored in MongoDB in Sagemaker studio, and both the MongoDB instance and Sagemaker studio domain is under the same VPC and security group, but I keep getting connection timeout error when I try to do it. Any help is appreciated.

I tried searching online and see if other people have ran into this problem as well but I haven't found any.

Comment: Does your SG allow traffic within itself? Can you try creating an EC2 instance with the same VPC and SG as SageMaker Studio, and try to connect to MongoDB from that EC2 instance? Also, is Studio in VPC only mode?